# Release Mode doesn't allow large textures

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, buffer, textures

Is there any setting in MS Visual Studio 2005 that will prevent OpenGL from allocating large textures? I am experiencing the following behavior:

**The situation:**

I create two large objects: one texture and one buffer both about 260 mb

**In Debug Mode:**

Allocation and use of both objects works fine. I can even destroy and recreate the objects several times with different but comparable sizes.

**In Release Mode:**

The Buffer is allocated but OpenGL throws [1] an OUT_OF_MEMORY error when i try to allocate the texture. At this point there is about 1000mb video memory available. [2]

Does anyone know some MSVC settings/parameters/whatever that can affect OpenGL in this way? *confused*

**Edit**

adding some code:

This is the place i create the buffer (called updateBuffer):

```
glm::u32 size = glm::compMul(size) * sizeof(glm::u16);

util::odprintf("[...] creating updatebuffer\n");
util::odprintf("[...] - for texture size: %s\n", glm::string(size).c_str());
util::odprintf("[...] - new size: %.2fkb\n", size / 1024.0f);

updateBuffer.create(size, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

util::odprintf("[...] - done\n");
```

At this point the buffer is mapped, data is written, the buffer is unmapped and the data is streamed to the graphics card. At the beginning of the next frame I create the texture:

```
util::odprintf("[...] initialize new data texture\n");
util::odprintf("[...] - available vram (before): %.2f\n", ogl::getCurrentAvailableVidMem() / 1024.0f);
util::odprintf("[...] - old texture: %d\n", newDataTexture());  // returns opengl handle
util::odprintf("[...] - new size: %s\n", glm::string(size).c_str());

newDataTexture.create(
    GL_R16F,        // internal format
    size,       // size
    0,      // border
    GL_RED,     // data format
    updateGLType,   // data type
    0);     // copy from buffer

util::odprintf("[...] - new texture %d\n", newDataTexture());
util::odprintf("[...] - available vram (after): %.2f\n", ogl::getCurrentAvailableVidMem() / 1024.0f);
```

(the buffer is of course bound to GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER before this)

The output is the same for release and debug build ... but in release OpenGL fails to create the texture:

```
[...] processing scheduled update
[...] creating updatebuffer
[...] - for texture size: ivec3(1376, 1040, 93)
[...] - new size: 259935.00kb
[...] - done
[...] update available
[...] initialize new data texture
[...] - available vram (before): 1004.09
[...] - old texture: 1
[...] - new size: ivec3(1376, 1040, 93)
Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) bei 0x7c812afb in ....exe: Microsoft C++-Ausnahme: ogl::debug_output an Speicherposition 0x0012dc68..
```

**Edit 2**

as by request: the code for the texture class

```
#pragma once

#include "GLTypes.h"

#include "ParameterTraits.h"
#include "Wrapper.h"
#include "TextureUnit.h"

namespace ogl {

namespace detail {


    template <>
    struct ReferenceHandler<gl_texture>
    {   
        static 
        void onDestroy(gl_texture & handle){
            TRACE("[Texture] destroying texture %d (%p)\n", handle, &handle);
            glDeleteTextures(1,&handle.t);
            handle = 0;
        };
    };
}


template <GLenum target>
struct texture_traits {};

template <>
struct texture_traits<GL_TEXTURE_1D> {
    typedef int size_t;
};

template <>
struct texture_traits<GL_TEXTURE_2D> {
    typedef glm::ivec2 size_t;
};

template <>
struct texture_traits<GL_TEXTURE_3D> {
    typedef glm::ivec3 size_t;
};



template <GLenum target>
class Texture : public detail::Wrapper<detail::gl_texture>, public detail::TextureUnit::Bindable
{
public:
    typedef typename texture_traits<target>::size_t size_t;

public:

    /**
     * \brief default constructor
     *
     * this actually doesn't do anything useful
     */
    Texture() : Wrapper<detail::gl_texture>() {
        glGenTextures(1,&object.t);
    };

    /**
     * \brief create new texture
     *
     * this constructs a new texture
     * the new texture will have a size and
     * will be empty
     *
     * \param internalFormat    texture format
     * \param size              texture size
     * \param border            texture border
     */
    void create(
        GLint internalFormat,
        size_t size,
        GLint border);

    /**
     * \brief create new texture
     *
     * this constructs a new texture
     * the new texture will have a size and
     * will be empty
     *
     * \param internalFormat    texture format
     * \param size              texture size
     * \param border            texture border
     * \param format            data format
     * \param type              data type
     */
    void create(
        GLint internalFormat,
        size_t size,
        GLint border,
        GLenum format,
        GLenum type,
        void * data);

    /** 
     * \brief virtual deconstructor
     */
    virtual ~Texture(void){};

    /**
     * \brief copy constructor
     */
    Texture & Texture::operator = (Texture const& rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            detail::Wrapper<detail::gl_texture>::operator=(rhs);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    /**
     * \brief update texture data
     *
     * update texture with new data
     *
     * \param level     texture level to update
     * \param offset    offset in texture
     * \param size      size of update data
     * \param format    data format
     * \param type      data type
     * \param data      data
     */
    void update(
        GLint level,
        size_t offset,
        size_t size,
        GLenum format,
        GLenum type,
        void * data);

    /**
     * \brief convenience method that updates the whole texture
     *
     * note: uses getters to determinate size of texture -> slow
     */
    void updateAll(
        GLint level,
        GLenum format,
        GLenum type,
        void * data);

    /**
     * \brief bind texture to texture unit
     *
     * this should not be included in texture. but texture unit is no real
     * object so this is defined here
     */

    void bind(GLenum texUnit) const
    {
        glBindMultiTextureEXT(texUnit, target, object);
    }

    // --- parameter access

    // - setters

    /**
     * \brief set texture parameters
     */
    template <typename T>
    void setParameter(GLenum name, T param);

    template <>
    void setParameter(GLenum name, GLint param)
    {
        glTextureParameteriEXT(object, target, name, param);
    }
    template <>
    void setParameter(GLenum name, GLfloat param)
    {
        glTextureParameterfEXT(object, target, name, param);
    }

    template <>
    void setParameter(GLenum name, GLint * param)
    {
        glTextureParameterivEXT(object, target, name, param);
    }
    template <>
    void setParameter(GLenum name, GLfloat * param)
    {
        glTextureParameterfvEXT(object, target, name, param);
    }

    // - getters

    /**
     * \brief get texture parameters
     */
    template <typename T>
    void getParameter(GLenum name, T & value);

    template <>
    void getParameter(GLenum name, GLfloat & value)
    {
        glGetTextureParameterfvEXT(
            object, target,
            name, &value);
    }
    template <>
    void getParameter(GLenum name, GLint & value)
    {
        glGetTextureParameterivEXT(
            object, target,
            name, &value);
    }

    // - level getters

    /**
     * \brief get texture level parameters
     */
    template <typename T>
    void getLevelParameter(GLint level, GLenum name, T & value);

    template <>
    void getLevelParameter(GLint level, GLenum name, GLint & value)
    {
        glGetTextureLevelParameterivEXT(
            object, target,
            level,
            name, &value);
    }

    template <>
    void getLevelParameter(GLint level, GLenum name, GLfloat & value)
    {
        glGetTextureLevelParameterfvEXT(
            object, target,
            level,
            name, &value);
    }



    /**
     * \brief generate mipmap levels for this texture
     */
    void generateMipmap() {
        glGenerateTextureMipmapEXT(object, target);
    }
};


// --- specialization for 1d texture

template <> 
inline void Texture<GL_TEXTURE_1D>::create(
    GLint internalFormat,
    GLint size,
    GLint border )
{
    //glGenTextures(1,&object.t);

    //std::vector<GLbyte> tmp(size*4);
    glTextureImage1DEXT(
        object,     // texture
        GL_TEXTURE_1D,          // target
        0,              // level
        internalFormat, // internal format
        size,           // size
        border,         // border
        GL_RGBA,        // format
        GL_BYTE,        // type
        0);     // don't load anything
}

template <> 
inline void Texture<GL_TEXTURE_1D>::create(
        GLint internalFormat,
        size_t size,
        GLint border,
        GLenum format,
        GLenum type,
        void * data)
{
    //glGenTextures(1,&object.t);

    glTextureImage1DEXT(
        object,                 // texture
        GL_TEXTURE_1D,          // target
        0,                      // level
        internalFormat,         // internal format
        size,                   // size
        border,                 // border
        format,                 // data format
        type,                   // data type
        data);                  // data
}

template <> 
inline void Texture<GL_TEXTURE_1D>::update(
    GLint level,
    GLint offset,
    GLint size,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    void * data )
{
    glTextureSubImage1DEXT(
        object,
        GL_TEXTURE_1D,
        level,
        offset,
        size, 
        format,
        type,
        data
        );
}

template <> 
inline void Texture<GL_TEXTURE_1D>::updateAll(
    GLint level,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    void * data)
{
    GLint size;
    glGetTextureLevelParameterivEXT(
        object,
        GL_TEXTURE_1D,
        level,
        GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH,
        &size
        );

    update(level, 0, size, format, type, data);
}

// --- specialization for 2d texture

template <> 
inline void Texture<GL_TEXTURE_2D>::create(
    GLint internalFormat,
    glm::ivec2 size,
    GLint border )
{
    //glGenTextures(1,&object.t);

    //std::vector<GLbyte> tmp(glm::compMul(size)*4);
    glTextureImage2DEXT(
        object,     // texture
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,          // target
        0,              // level
        internalFormat, // internal format
        size.x, size.y, // size
        border,         // border
        GL_RGBA,        // format
        GL_BYTE,        // type
        0);     // don't load anything
}

template <> 
inline void Texture<GL_TEXTURE_2D>::create(
        GLint internalFormat,
        size_t size,
        GLint border,
        GLenum format,
        GLenum type,
        void * data)
{
    //glGenTextures(1,&object.t);

    glTextureImage2DEXT(
        object,                 // texture
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,          // target
        0,                      // level
        internalFormat,         // internal format
        size.x, size.y,         // size
        border,                 // border
        format,                 // data format
        type,                   // data type
        data);                  // data
}

template <> 
inline void Texture<GL_TEXTURE_2D>::update(
    GLint level,
    glm::ivec2 offset,
    glm::ivec2 size,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    void * data )
{
    glTextureSubImage2DEXT(
        object,
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        level,
        offset.x, offset.y,
        size.x, size.y,
        format,
        type,
        data
        );
}

template <> 
inline void Texture<GL_TEXTURE_2D>::updateAll(
    GLint level,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    void * data)
{
    glm::ivec2 size;
    glGetTextureLevelParameterivEXT(
        object,
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        level,
        GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH,
        &size.x
        );
    glGetTextureLevelParameterivEXT(
        object,
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        level,
        GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT,
        &size.y
        );

    update(level, glm::ivec2(0,0), size, format, type, data);
}

// --- specialization for 3d texture

template <> 
inline void Texture<GL_TEXTURE_3D>::create(
    GLint internalFormat,
    glm::ivec3 size,
    GLint border )
{
    //glGenTextures(1,&object.t);

    //std::vector<GLbyte> tmp(glm::compMul(size)*4);
    glTextureImage3DEXT(
        object,                 // texture
        GL_TEXTURE_3D,          // target
        0,                      // level
        internalFormat,         // internal format
        size.x, size.y, size.z, // size
        border,                 // border
        GL_RGBA,                // format
        GL_BYTE,                // type
        0);             // don't load anything
}

template <> 
inline void Texture<GL_TEXTURE_3D>::create(
        GLint internalFormat,
        size_t size,
        GLint border,
        GLenum format,
        GLenum type,
        void * data)
{
    //glGenTextures(1,&object.t);

    glTextureImage3DEXT(
        object,                 // texture
        GL_TEXTURE_3D,          // target
        0,                      // level
        internalFormat,         // internal format
        size.x, size.y, size.z, // size
        border,                 // border
        format,                 // data format
        type,                   // data type
        data);                  // data
}

template <> 
inline void Texture<GL_TEXTURE_3D>::update(
    GLint level,
    glm::ivec3 offset,
    glm::ivec3 size,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    void * data ) 
{
    glTextureSubImage3DEXT(
        object,
        GL_TEXTURE_3D,
        level,
        offset.x, offset.y, offset.z,
        size.x, size.y, size.z,
        format,
        type,
        data
        );
}

template <> 
inline void Texture<GL_TEXTURE_3D>::updateAll(
    GLint level,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    void * data)
{
    glm::ivec3 size;
    glGetTextureLevelParameterivEXT(
        object,
        GL_TEXTURE_3D,
        level,
        GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH,
        &size.x
        );
    glGetTextureLevelParameterivEXT(
        object,
        GL_TEXTURE_3D,
        level,
        GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT,
        &size.y
        );
    glGetTextureLevelParameterivEXT(
        object,
        GL_TEXTURE_3D,
        level,
        GL_TEXTURE_DEPTH,
        &size.z
        );

    update(level, glm::ivec3(0,0,0), size, format, type, data);
}

typedef Texture<GL_TEXTURE_1D> Texture1d;
typedef Texture<GL_TEXTURE_2D> Texture2d;
typedef Texture<GL_TEXTURE_3D> Texture3d;

};
```

As you can see i am using EXT_direct_state_access. The "Wrapper" class is a standard refcounted design. I can't disclose that one ... but i can say for sure that it is proven to work.

Please keep asking if you need to know more ... i am running out of ideas here. :(

** The solution **

man ... someone had disabled /LARGEMEMORYAWARE in the release build ... thanks to everyone who tried to warp their head around this :)

[1] I am using ARB_debug_output
[2] checked with GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info

Comment: please show some code, maybe you mistakenly allocate more than you think.

Comment: what's `newDataTexture()`? it looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: oh sorry ... newDataTexture is the variable name ... the texture class overrides operator() and returns the opengl handle like in the opengl c++ api ... (did i mention i hate c++ for readability reasons?)

Comment: We can't help you much with your OpenGL code unless you show us some OpenGL code.  I've never heard of any "opengl c++ api".  The OpenGL API is straight C.

Comment: Does the problem also occur in VC2008 and VC2010?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: sorry ... but VC2005 is all i have here.

Comment: @Alan: as i said below: this is an inhouse c++ wrapper around the c library. It utilizes EXT_direct_state_access and ARB_debug_output to get some object'esque functionality out of OpenGL

Comment: @Florian: Some of this code is edited for posting, isn't it?  `glm::u32 size = glm::compMul(size) * sizeof(glm::u16);` isn't right, the variable is used in calculating its own initial value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using OpenGL, you are using some C++ library that in turn uses OpenGL.  I would look there for your problem.

Is this library pure header files (recompiled from source in your project, using your compiler settings), or is there a binary component?  Binary libraries typically don't deal well with changed compiler settings, such as the difference between Debug and Release configuration.

Comment: This is an inhouse c++ library. Actually it's just a thin header library around the opengl objects. I don't think that there is a problem in the library.

Comment: @Florian: We can't help unless you show us at least the portion of the code that's failing.  That means the implementation of the `create` function you are calling.  While VC++ compiler/library bugs aren't unheard of, as a rule of thumb the bug is MUCH more likely to be in your library, or even the nVidia display driver.  Unless you think your library has gone through more code review and testing than the compiler, which I highly doubt.

Comment: @Florian: My answer is so far off the mark, it shouldn't be accepted.  Instead, post your solution as an answer and then accept your own answer.